# ng-show through controller is not working

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a page with 3 elements. first search bar, second search result area and third form. so here use case is like, by default search bar and form div will be showing and hiding the search result div. If i enter keys on search bar then i get the client data and so want to hide form bar and show the search bar result. In search var result if i click any one of item(client) then hide the search result and show the form div. And then i want to fill clicked client name in form field, i am new in angularjs please help me out.

```
<ion-view title="Client Details" id="page5" ng-init="isSearch=false;isForm=true;" style="background-color:#F1F8E9;">
<ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
  <label class="item item-input">
      <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
      <input type="search" ng-model="str" ng-change="searchByName(str)" placeholder="Search Client">
  </label>
  <ion-list ng-show="{{isSearch}}" id="home-list2">
        <ion-item ng-repeat="client in clientList" id="home-list-item2" ng-click="str=true">{{client.name}}</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <form ng-show="{{isForm}}" id="clientDetails-form1" class="list ">
        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" id="clientDetails-input1">
            <span class="input-label">Name</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
        </label>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

And my controller file is

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('clientdetailsctrl', ['clientdetailsservice']);
app.run(function($rootScope, $state, ClientDetails) {

});

app.controller('ClientDetailsCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $state, ClientDetails) {
    $scope.searchByName = function(str) {
        $scope.isSearch = true;
        $scope.isForm = false;
        $scope.clientList = [];
        ClientDetails.searchByName($scope, str);
    };
});})();
```

here i am trying to change the values of isSearch and isForm values, but no luck.

Comment: are you getting any error in your console?

Answer (score 6):

change:

```
ng-show="{{isForm}}"
```

to

```
ng-show="isForm"
```

You dont have to force evaluation of a ng-show

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Comment: Thanks niles! Solved